# Exception not catching overflow or underflow in C++

Tags: c++, exception, overflow, underflow

Exception not catching if two numbers are overflowing.

The output only printing the wrong number which is negative.

```
Test operator*(const Test &object) const
{
    try
    {
        return Test(value * object.value);
    }
    catch (std::overflow_error &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (std::underflow_error &e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

In main:

```
Test t1(533222220);
Test t2(300002222);
Test t = t1 * t2; // does not throw exception but  t1 * t2 -1416076888
```

Comment: What is value? Please post [mcve]. If value is an integral type, multiplication never throws exceptions.

Comment: Arithmetic overflow is not required to throw an exception.

Comment: @S.M. — until recently, signed arithmetic overflow resulted in undefined behavior, so it **could** throw an exception. In practice, of course, it never did.

Comment: @PeteBecker I think they're still undefined, despite the guaranteed two's complement.

Answer (score 3):

> Exception not catching if two numbers are overflowing.

Correct. No exceptions are thrown by integer arithmetic. If signed integer operation overflows, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Despite how it sounds like, `std::overflow_error` and `std::underflow_error` does not detect arithmetic overflow and underflow by default. In standard library, `overflow_error` is only used for converting `bitset` to number, and `underflow_error` is never used. Any other overflow and underflow must be checked manually.

For more about how to detect overflows, you might check: [How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

In *standard* C++, `catch` blocks only work with `throw` statements, and there are no `throw` statements in the code you have shown.

Some compilers have *vendor extensions* that may convert non-exception errors, like integer overflows, into C++ exceptions, but your example is clearly not a case of that happening.